# In what degree/to what degree

Tags: construction

I was doing a chapter in my grammar and there I found the following sentences

> This mango is very sweet 
>   In this sentence, very shows **in what degree** the mango is sweet.

What my confusion is

We use **to what degree** but here **in what degree** is used and it sounds very weird.

Comment: I agree with you that "to what degree" seems more natural.

Comment: Can you specify the name of the source please?

Comment: Please include the book's title. It's important to know if the author is a native speaker, if the book was published recently, if the quotation is used as an example of correct usage or not, if you copied the text precisely/accurately.

Comment: Wren and Martin

Comment: You're supposed to include that information IN the question. Please tell us **the title of the book**. Good thing I checked back, and saw the comment. In order to communicate directly with users, in the comment section, use @ followed by their username.

Answer (score 3):

I never found "**in what degree**" until now in my experience. "**To what degree**" is the most common variant.

I suspect that "**in what degree**" is actually English words fit to foreign grammar.

Compare:

> ***În*** ce măsură este mango dulce?

Word-to-word translation into English:

> ***In*** what measure (degree) is mango sweet?

It is possible that the author of the original text is a non-native English speaker - which explains the unusual text.

Answer (score 1):

These two are grammatically correct.

Q: "To what degree was the mango sweet?"/ "In what degree was the mango sweet?"
A: "Very sweet"

Comment: Will you please explain why are those correct? Without an explanation, OP cannot learn English better. Just providing examples is usually not enough - and in this case, it is not enough. Please edit your answer and add more details.

Answer (score 0):

According to Merriam-Webster, ["*to* what degree"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/to%20what%20degree) means "how much." ["*In* what degree"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/in%20what%20degree) is not even in the dictionary, but both phrases can be found in formal texts; the search in Google site:gov for:

- ["*to* what degree"](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&hl=en&authuser=0&ei=FHX3XL_sE4KVsAeM05SgCQ&q=site%3Agov%20%22to%20what%20degree%22&oq=site%3Agov%20%22to%20what%20degree%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...281723.282477..282747...0.0..0.116.286.3j1......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71.9bwE0gbxvoM) gives 125,000 results
- ["*in* what degree"](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&hl=en&authuser=0&ei=D3X3XNnfO8KckgWP3oSIDw&q=site%3Agov%20%22in%20what%20degree%22&oq=site%3Agov%20%22in%20what%20degree%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...2563.3225..3640...0.0..0.61.227.4......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71.EfR76PSV3rQ) gives 28,400 results

Comment: Is "Ludwig.guru" a native or proficient speaker of English? Just provide credible sources. Further, the number of results Google reports is an **estimate** (and often wrong) which also doesn't take context into account. All in all, none of what you've presented here is meaningful in the way you're trying to make it seem – as proof of idiomatic English. (–1)

Comment: Gov sites include pubmed.gov and many other medical and nutrition-related websites, most of which probably use idiomatic English. Merriam-Webster is also probably a credible source.

Answer (score -1):

It is not incorrect to use ***"in what degree"***, but the most common way of saying it is ***"to what degree"***.

**Some statistics:**

> IN AMERICAN ENGLISH

```
"TO WHAT DEGREE" occurred 99.01%
"IN WHAT DEGREE" occurred 00.98%
```

> IN BRITISH ENGLISH

```
"TO WHAT DEGREE" occurred 98.94%
"IN WHAT DEGREE" occurred 01.06%
```

> IN CANADIAN ENGLISH

```
"TO WHAT DEGREE" occurred 95.95%
"IN WHAT DEGREE" occurred 04.05%
```

> IN THE ENGLISH USED IN IRELAND

```
"TO WHAT DEGREE" occurred 99.97%
"IN WHAT DEGREE" occurred 00.03%
```

> IN AUSTRALIAN ENGLISH

```
"TO WHAT DEGREE" occurred 98.46%
"IN WHAT DEGREE" occurred 01.54%
```

> IN NEW ZEALAND ENGLISH

```
"TO WHAT DEGREE" occurred 99.98%
"IN WHAT DEGREE" occurred 00.02%
```

> IN INDIAN ENGLISH

```
"TO WHAT DEGREE" occurred 95.65%
"IN WHAT DEGREE" occurred 04.35%
```

This statistics shows the degree of rarity of ***"in what degree"***. No wonder you being an Indian, as that is what I suppose, found that phrase in your Indian book. Interestingly there is no occurrence of ***"in what degree"*** in the English used in your neighboring countries, that is Pakistan and Sri Lanka (during the period this statics is based on).